# Directory listing when using setfacl ACL

Tags: directory, ls, setfacl

I use setfacl command to grant read permission for reading files in directory, but I cant use ls to view files. I tried

```
setfacl -Rdm g:grouptoadd:rx /path/directory/
```

but, I can read files (when I use direct path to file for example "/path/directory/myfile) and can't list directory (ls /path/directory/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the **"grouptoadd"** does not have execute permission on the **path** directory. You can `ls /path/directory/` only if you have execute permission on all directories that make your path.

Try `$ getfacl /path` and make sure that the "**grouptoadd**" has execute permission.

If not, you can simple add it: `$ setfacl -m g:grouptoadd:x /path`.

Also, use `setfacl` command without `-d` option.

Answer (score 0):

As I tested it works when I don't use `d` option, which means default.

```
setfacl -Rdm g:grouptoadd:rx /path/directory/
```

that command permits new files in the directory `rx` permission.

```
setfacl -Rm g:grouptoadd:rx /path/directory/
```

that command permits `grouptoadd` group to list and read the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting **default ACLs** via `-d` flag, not **effective ACLs**. Default ACLs is mechanism to set ACLs for files and directories which are created within the directory you are setting default ACLs for. Remove the `-d` option if you want to apply the ACLs to the directory itself.

If you do `getfacl` you will see "default" entries. I suggest to read more about Linux ACLs.

```
[lzap@x1 foreman-packaging-rpm]$ getfacl /tmp/test
# file: tmp/test
# owner: lzap
# group: lzap
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

[lzap@x1 foreman-packaging-rpm]$ setfacl -dm u:lzap:rx /tmp/test

[lzap@x1 foreman-packaging-rpm]$ getfacl /tmp/test
# file: tmp/test
# owner: lzap
# group: lzap
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:lzap:r-x
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

[lzap@x1 foreman-packaging-rpm]$ setfacl -m u:lzap:rx /tmp/test

[lzap@x1 foreman-packaging-rpm]$ getfacl /tmp/test
# file: tmp/test
# owner: lzap
# group: lzap
user::rwx
user:lzap:r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:lzap:r-x
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

To see default ACLs in action, just create a file within a directory with a default ACL. In my case `touch /tmp/test/a_file` and it will inherit the `u:lzap:r-x` ACL.